# Need to help query with based on condition in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a question about SQL Server.

Table: `Dimemp`

```
          empkey   |  empid | name |loc
            1      |  100   | abc  |Hyd
            2      |  102   | def  |chen
            3      |  -1    | NA   |beng
```

Table2 : `dimdept`

```
        deptkey  |  deptno  | deptname
        1        |  10      |Hr
        2        |  20      |ceo
        3        |  -1      |NA
```

Transaction table: `tranemp`

```
empid    |  deptno   |  projectname |codes
100      |   20      |   test       |100
104      |   10      |   deve       |101
102      |   10      |  test        |107
106      |   40      |   sap        |103
101      |           |  Ca          |100
         |   10      |  manual      |201
100      |   60      |  quality     |100
```

Here the `transedmp` table data look into dimensions table if records match exact record then  retrieve corresponding keys .if records not match then we need to fill defaule values -1 corresponding key value common columns for traneemp and dimension tables.   empid(tranemp)=dimemp(empid) and tranemp(deptno)=dimdept(deptno)

Based on tranemp table I want output like below

```
    empkey   | deptkey    | projectname   | codes
    1        |  2         |   test        |100
    3        |  1         |   deve        |101
    2        |  1         |   test        |107
    3        |  3         |    sap        |103
    3        |  3         |    Ca         |100
    3        |  1         |   manual      |201
    1        |  3         |  quality      |100
```

I tried like this:

```
 select 
     a.empkey, b.deptkey, c.projectname, c.codes 
 from  
     traneemp c 
 inner join
     dimemp  a on a.empid = c.empid 
 inner join  
     dimdept b on b.deptno = c.deptno
```

I am not able to get expected result. Please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use left join to get all result even if they don't match and in case they are null get the default value.

```
select ISNULL(a.empkey, (select empkey from Dimemp where empid = -1)),
       ISNULL(b.deptkey, (select deptkey from dimdept where deptno = -1)), 
       c.projectname, c.codes 
from  traneemp c 
left join dimemp a on a.empid=c.empid
left join dimdept b on b.deptno=c.deptno
```